# as3 check to see if item in array has been clicked

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, button

Sorry if this is a little n00b-ish.  I'm working in AS3. I've got an array of 8 buttons.  I'm currently hiding the button that is clicked using e.currentTarget.

How can I tell flash to make all the buttons that **aren't** the currentTarget to become visible (i.e. if a button has been hidden by previously being clicked, how do I tell it to become visible again when another button is clicked?)

Thanks in advance for any advice.  Below is what I am using to hide the parent of the currentTarget:

```
buttonArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, officeButtonSelected);
    function officeButtonSelected (e:MouseEvent){
        e.currentTarget.parent.visible=false;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you detect a click, simply loop over all buttons and make them visible before hiding the one that was clicked.

```
for each( var button:DisplayObject in buttonArray){
    button.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks grapefrukt, you rock!  I simply added .parent to button and it worked.  Much appreciated.